# Does byte alignment occur when data is transfered from main memory to GPUmemory?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have data struct in both glsl and C++:

```
struct LentiStruct
{
    vec2 center;
    float radius;
};
```

And I use a shader storage buffer to contain an array of such struct in glsl:

```
layout(std430, binding = 2) buffer Lents
{
    LentiStruct in_lents[];
};
```

So I think the actual size of such struct array should be in_lents.length()*(2+2)*4 bytes if I consider the byte alignment when use qualifier std430.

Then I update the buffer with glBufferSubData():

```
std::vector<LentiCircle> &l;
...
Gluint ssbo;
...
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ssbo);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, l.size()*sizeof(LentiStruct), &l[0]);
```

Everything works fine, but I think the size here doesn't match that in glsl, why it still works fine? Shouldn't I take byte alignment into consideration?

Comment: Is vec2 a class or a POD?

Comment: @Devolus its a class glm::vec2

Comment: @Devolus: POD's *are* classes.

Comment: @NicolBolas, not always, because if a class uses i.e. virtual functions it is no longer POD, and in this case it might not work to pass such an array into the GL buffer.

Comment: @Devolus: All PODs are classes, but not all classes are PODs.

Comment: @NicolBolas, correct, and now think about what this means in terms of passing it into a GL buffer...